# SublimeText3 - Keeps switching back to default color scheme

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublimetext3, color-scheme

I just installed sublime text 3 and some themes/color scheme packages and [schemr](https://github.com/benweier/Schemr) and switched color scheme (using schemr) but ST3 keeps switching it back to default monokai. Is there some other recommended way of switching color schemes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to [open an issue](https://github.com/benweier/Schemr/issues/new) with the maintainer of Schemr, describing exactly what's going on, what settings you have, and what (if anything) causes the scheme to switch back to Monokai.

Browsing through [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/search), I found the following possible substitutes for Sublime Text 3:

- [QuickThemes](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/QuickThemes), which allows you to cycle through any Sublime Text Preference, including color schemes and themes.
- [Helios](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Helios), which allows you to switch between two color schemes and two themes at the same time - the idea being, I suppose, to set a "dark" theme/scheme pair for nighttime work, and a "light" pair for daytime.
- [ColorSchemeSelector](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ColorSchemeSelector), which allows you to pick a scheme via a quick panel. For me it detected both the default and third-party color schemes, but didn't seem to find all the schemes included as part of other packages. YMMV :)
- [ThemeScheduler](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ThemeScheduler) allows you to rotate through color schemes depending on the time of day, as well as optionally modify the colors, tones, etc. using the author's [ThemeTweaker](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ThemeTweaker) color filtering plugin.

All of them do slightly different things and require slightly different amounts of setup, so check them all out and see which one(s) you like. Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks for help! `ColorSchemeSelector` successfully changed the color scheme, but after using it I again tried `Schemr` and it worked flawlessly too, I guess there was some issue with ST3 which `Schemr` wasn't able to overcome.